# XML file reading in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

Is it necessary to know the structure and tags of an XML file completely before reading it in Java?

```
areaElement.getElementsByTagName("checked").item(0).getTextContent()
```

I don't know the field name "checked" before I read the file. Is there any way to list all the tags in the XML file, basically the file structure?

Comment: You may get some thing here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255529/how-to-extract-xml-tag-value-without-using-the-tag-name-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had  prepared this DOM parser by myself, using recursion which will parse your xml  without having knowledge of single tag. It will give you each node's text content if exist, in a sequence. You can remove commented section in following code to get node name also. Hope it would help.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileInputStream;  
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;  
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;  
 import org.w3c.dom.Document;  
 import org.w3c.dom.Node;  
 import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;  



public class RecDOMP {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
        dbf.setValidating(false); 
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();   

// replace following  path with your input xml path  
         Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File  ("D:\\ambuj\\ATT\\apip\\APIP_New.xml")));  

// replace following  path with your output xml path 
         File OutputDOM = new File("D:\\ambuj\\ATT\\apip\\outapip1.txt");
            FileOutputStream fostream = new FileOutputStream(OutputDOM);
            OutputStreamWriter oswriter = new OutputStreamWriter (fostream);
            BufferedWriter bwriter = new BufferedWriter(oswriter);

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!OutputDOM.exists()) {
                OutputDOM.createNewFile();}


            visitRecursively(doc,bwriter);
            bwriter.close(); oswriter.close(); fostream.close();

            System.out.println("Done");
}
public static void visitRecursively(Node node, BufferedWriter bw) throws IOException{  

             // get all child nodes  
         NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();                                  
         for (int i=0; i<list.getLength(); i++) {          
                 // get child node              
       Node childNode = list.item(i);  
       if (childNode.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
       {
   //System.out.println("Found Node: " + childNode.getNodeName()           
    //   + " - with value: " + childNode.getNodeValue()+" Node type:"+childNode.getNodeType()); 

   String nodeValue= childNode.getNodeValue();
   nodeValue=nodeValue.replace("\n","").replaceAll("\\s","");
   if (!nodeValue.isEmpty())
   {
       System.out.println(nodeValue);
       bw.write(nodeValue);
       bw.newLine();
   }
       }
       visitRecursively(childNode,bw);  

            }         

     }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely check out libraries for this, like dom4j (http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/).  They can parse the whole XML document and let you not only list things like elements but do XPath queries and other such cool stuff on them.

There is a performance hit, especially in large XML documents, so you will want to check on the performance hit for your use case before committing to a library.  This is especially true if you only need a small bit out of the XML document (and you kind of know what you are looking for already).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is no, it is not necessary to know any element names in advance. For example, you can walk the tree to discover the element names. But it all depends what you are actually trying to do.

For the vast majority of applications, incidentally, the Java DOM is one of the worst ways to solve the problem. But I won't comment further without knowing your project requirements.